Activating Azure real-time streaming TTS Avatar through REST calls
I am playing around with Azure real-time Text-to-speech (TTS) avatar, and for my use case I don't want the activation of speech synthesize to be controlled by the frontend web application.
I want the streamed TTS avatar to be activated from another backend service that just send rest calls to the TTS service with whatever text the avatar needs to synthesize.
However I have been unable to find a way to do so and can only find documentation for how to operate the TTS avatar through websockets from the frontend web app with microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk.AvatarSynthesizer.
Do anyone know if microsoft has an rest rendpoint that can synthesize speech to an open TTS avatar websocket stream given its ID?

What "TTS Avatar" service are you referring to?

This one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/text-to-speech-avatar/what-is-text-to-speech-avatar. Do they have more?

@Benjamin any luck on finding a solution, as I'm looking for something to?
